# How to get both name and value of variable in a macro?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

Is it possible to make a Rust macro that can access both the name and value of a variable passed as a parameter?

```rust
let my_variable: i32 = 5;
printvar!(my_variable); // => to print "my_variable = 5"
```

For example with C macros we can use the `#` operator:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT_VAR(x) printf("%s = %d\n", #x, x);

 int main() {
    int my_variable = 5;
    PRINT_VAR(my_variable);
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
my_variable = 5
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent of `#` in Rust is the [`stringify!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html):

```rust
macro_rules! print_var {
    ($var: ident) => {
        println!("{} = {}", stringify!($var), $var);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_variable = 5;
    // prints my_variable = 5
    print_var!(my_variable);
}
```